# Rails Console 'helper' and 'app' Appear Incomplete

Tags: ruby-on-rails, helper, rails-console

Using ruby 2.3.0 and rails 4.2.5.1, I'm trying to figure some things
out using the rails console. I have several instances where `app` or `helper` seem like they have a method I want, but I often end up with the NoMethodError message. This happens even in a brand-new application where I've edited nothing and given no special options to the `rails new` command. For instance:

```
irb(main):015:0* helper.timez
```

... here I hit `TAB` to get:

```
irb(main):015:0* helper.timezone
```

... and hit `ENTER`, only to find:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `timezone' for #<ActionView::Base:0xc662b80>
```

Why would tab-expansion in the console expand to methods that don't
exist? More importantly, if they're supposed to be there, why aren't
they? What can I be doing wrong?

Comment: correct syntax is rather Time.now.zone. I am not sure what is shown when tab is pressed. But I do see such.

Comment: Hi Maxence, I know that this is the correct syntax for the Time class. The helper, on the other hand, has a bunch of methods that I'm sure are simply thin wrappers around a bunch of other calls, and I was asking more about those. But thanks.